# Placing one 0 (zero) instead of several 0's in a td tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

Here is my html,

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sl</th>
        <th>Book</th>
        <th th:each="inventory: ${inventories}" th:text="${inventory.name}"></th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="book, bookCount : ${books}">
        <td th:text="${bookCount.index}+1"></td>
        <td th:text="${book.name}"></td>
        <td th:each="inventory, inventoryCount : ${inventories}">
            <span th:each="inventoryDetails, inventoryDetailsCount : ${inventoryDetailsList}">
                <span th:if="${inventory eq inventoryDetails.inventory}">
                    <span  th:text="${inventoryDetails.book eq book}? ${inventoryDetails.bookQuantity} : 0"></span>
                </span>

            </span>
        </td>
        <td th:text="${book.inventoryQuantity}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the current output,
[image]

*Case 1: **Book 3 in Inventory 0***

**Currently showing :** 0 0 0

**Expected :** 0

*Case 2: **Book 0 in Inventory 0** or **Book 1 in Inventory 0***

**Currently showing :** 0 0 20 or 0 20 0

**Expected :** 20

You can see the ideal scenario under **Inventory 2**

Can you please suggest me a solution about how can I get the **expected** result using jquery?

Here is the rendered Html,

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sl</th>
        <th>Book</th>
        <th>Inventory 0</th>
        <th>Inventory 1</th>
        <th>Inventory 2</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Book 5</td>
        <td>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>50</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
        </td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Book 1</td>
        <td>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>20</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
        </td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Book 0</td>
        <td>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>20</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>60</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>40</span>
                </span>

            </span>
        </td>
        <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Book 3</td>
        <td>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>10</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
        </td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML instead of the script that generates it, since the JavaScript will work on the resulting HTML?

Comment: @DavidThomas added the rendered html.

Comment: In this case - it is better to check background code logic, imho, rather than change rendered HTML...

Comment: While you've already accepted an answer, do you prefer to retain the nested `<span>` elements, or remove them?

Comment: @DavidThomas, I prefer to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is one solution. Not so elegant (had to use few each loops), but it is working:

```js
$('.table-striped td').each(function() {
//spantext=$(this).find('span').text().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');

$(this).find('span').each(function( index ) {

spantext=$(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');

if(spantext=='0') {

$(this).remove();
}


});

});

$('.table-striped td').each(function() {
if(!($.trim($(this).text()).length)) {
$(this).html('<span>0</span>')
}
});
```

```css
table,th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sl</th>
        <th>Book</th>
        <th>Inventory 0</th>
        <th>Inventory 1</th>
        <th>Inventory 2</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Book 5</td>
        <td>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>50</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
        </td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Book 1</td>
        <td>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>20</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
        </td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Book 0</td>
        <td>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>20</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>60</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>40</span>
                </span>

            </span>
        </td>
        <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Book 3</td>
        <td>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>10</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>


            </span>
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>0</span>
                </span>

            </span>
        </td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, idea is - find spans with (only) zeroes, remove it, rebuild td's HTML (second loop). If i find more elegant solution, i will post it...

Comment: you are just great. This solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tareq, np, glad to help. Since HTML structure is, huh... so strange (multiple spans inside spans) - maybe this is not bad solution at all. :)

Comment: Of course it is a Good solution. All those spans showed up just because number of conditions followed by number of loops... :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach, using plain JavaScript, is the following:

```
// a named function, in case you might need to use it
// more than once:
function repeatedToSingle(opts) {

  // using 'let' (instead of 'var') to declare variables,
  // this requires ES6 (or above) compliant browsers; for
  // ES5 or below simply use 'var' instead.
  // Here we set the defaults for the function:
  // 'character' : String, the character that we wish
  //               to remove repeated instances of,
  // 'ignoreCase': Boolean,
  //                 true: we ignore the case of the
  //                 character, and use a case-insensitive
  //                 search ('P' will match 'p'),
  //                 false: we respect the case of the
  //                 supplied character ('P' will not match 'p'),
  // 'table' :     the <table> element within which to search,
  // 'amendedClassName' : String, the class-name to add to the
  //                      elements that this function changes;
  //                      Boolean false, or an empty String,
  //                      prevents a class-name from being added.
  let settings = {
    'character': '0',
    'ignoreCase': false,
    'table': document.querySelector('table'),
    'amendedClassName': 'amended'
  };


  // Here we use Object.keys() to return an Array of the keys for
  // the supplied opts Object, if supplied, or an empty Object
  // (in order to prevent throwing an error), and iterating
  // over that array of keys using Array.prototype.forEach():
  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(

    // using an Arrow function to set the value of the opts key
    // as the property-value of the settings key (to allow the
    // user to override the default settings):
    key => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  // declaring a regular expression, using the new RegExp()
  // constructor, in order to allow us to interpolate the
  // supplied character with the beginning of string ('^'),
  // and the one-or-more ('+') and end-of-string ('$')
  // special characters, and setting the case-insensitive flag
  // ('i') for the regular expression based on whether the
  // settings.ignoreCase property is set to true or false:
  let regex = new RegExp('^' + settings.character + '+$', settings.ignoreCase === true ? 'i' : '');

  // here we using Element.querySelectorAll() to find those
  // <td> elements that are contained within a <tbody> element,
  // using Array.from() to convert that NodeList into an Array,
  // filtering that Array with Array.prototype.filter(), and its
  // Arrow function:
  return Array.from(settings.table.querySelectorAll('tbody td')).filter(

    // cell is a reference to the current <td> element of the Array
    // of Elements over which we're iterating.
    // here we're testing that the text-content of the cell, after
    // replacing all sequences of one-or-more ('+') white-spaces
    // with empty Strings matches the created regular expression;
    // RegExp.test() returns a Boolean, true if the supplied String
    // matches the test, and false if not; if the result is true
    // the element is retained in the Array, otherwise discarded:
    cell => regex.test(cell.textContent.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ''))

  // Array.prototype.forEach() is used to iterate over the remaining
  // <td> elements in the Array, using an Arrow function:
  ).forEach(cell => {

    // if we have a truthy value for settings.amendedClassName
    // and we have a length for that value:
    if (settings.amendedClassName && settings.amendedClassName.length) {

      // we use the Element.classList API to add that class-name to
      // the current <td>:
      cell.classList.add(settings.amendedClassName);
    }

    // setting the text-content of the current <td> to the
    // supplied character:
    cell.textContent = settings.character;
  });

  // this function also returns the filtered Array, which is the
  // Array of modified cells, in the event that the user may
  // want to store a reference.

}

repeatedToSingle();
```

```js
function repeatedToSingle(opts) {
  let settings = {
    'character': '0',
    'ignoreCase': false,
    'table': document.querySelector('table'),
    'amendedClassName': 'amended'
  };

  Object.keys(opts || {}).forEach(
    key => settings[key] = opts[key]
  );

  let regex = new RegExp('^' + settings.character + '+$', settings.ignoreCase === true ? 'i' : '');
  return Array.from(settings.table.querySelectorAll('tbody td')).filter(
    cell => regex.test(cell.textContent.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ''))
  ).forEach(cell => {
    if (settings.amendedClassName && settings.amendedClassName.length) {
      cell.classList.add(settings.amendedClassName);
    }
    cell.textContent = settings.character;
  });

}

repeatedToSingle();
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0;
}

.amended {
  color: #f90;
}

.ffs {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sl</th>
      <th>Book</th>
      <th>Inventory 0</th>
      <th>Inventory 1</th>
      <th>Inventory 2</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Book 5</td>
      <td>
        <span>
          <span>
            <span>50</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span>
            <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
          <span>
            <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Book 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>20</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Book 0</td>
      <td>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>20</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>60</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>40</span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Book 3</td>
      <td>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>10</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        </span>
        <span>
        <span>
        <span>0</span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rbL9go92/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototoype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototoype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Conditional 'ternary' Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/conditional_operator).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace/).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim/).
- [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).